# Custom html borders from image

Tags: html, css, image, styles, border

Is it possible to create a custom border for an html table from an image that i create? I am using adobe fireworks and want to use one of their brushes as my table border.  So far I have only found how to use the preset border like the following:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
.table{
    border-style:outset;
    border-color: red;
    border-width:10px;
      }
</style>
```

Instead of using the border style: outset, I would like to create my own.  The code from above was based on code from [This website](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol5/css_no5.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not well supported across browsers, but you should have a look at the css3 attribute `border-image`:

```
-moz-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
```

IE is the odd man out here, but otherwise it should work well. There's a good article here: http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 supports image borders: http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/border-image-anim.html but browser support is poor on IE http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image